# It possible to run command with web access to files?

Tags: linux, security, web, openafs

Have a Linux server with OpenAFS and access to / files.

Access is read-only and like user privileges (ex. can read `/etc/passwd`, but can't read `/etc/shadow`).

It possible to run command? With `/bin/bash` for example?

And, on server have sshd service, but don't have rights to `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you want to run the script: on the server or on the client?

Comment: On client, because I don't have any access to server.

Comment: What is the problem? `cd` to your mount point and run whatever script you like.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.